# Compiling with Mono: System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.2.0 -> The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to compile a program called ChatDaemon (coded with Visual Studio 2017, in C#, on a Windows 8.0 machine) with Mono Command Prompt x64. The Mono compiler provides the following error report upon failing:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (TaskId:24)
C:\Program Files\Mono\lib\mono\msbuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code 1.

After doing several hours of research, I have inserted these lines into ChatDaemon.csproj, to no avail:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have also already inserted the following lines into the App.config file for ChatDaemon, also to no avail.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.FileSystem" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0" newVersion="4.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I am using the following version of .NET Framework, as found in the ChatDaemon.csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2">
          <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I also found this piece of code in the ChatDaemon.csproj file, pertaining to the System.IO.FileSystem.dll file:

```
<Reference Include="System.IO.FileSystem">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.io.filesystem\4.3.0\ref\net46\System.IO.FileSystem.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

How should I go about fixing this error? If more information is needed, let me know and I will comply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
> <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.io.filesystem\4.3.0\ref\net46\System.IO.FileSystem.dll</HintPath>
```

to the standard .NET .dll
The issue could be caused by the Nuget package. The file in System.IO.FileSystem-package is not versioned as 4.3.0, according to [this site](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16322).

```
<Reference Include="system.io.filesystem">
    </Reference>
```

Alternatively you could try using the Filesystem-dlls in the other subfolders of the nuget package depending on what Framework you use. (for example NuGetFallbackFolder\System.IO.FileSystem.4.3.0\lib\net46)